# How can I refer to Excel columns by their header names rather than indexes/keys in Selenium Webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests, telerik-test-studio

I just recently started a job writing automated tests using Selenium WebDriver and Java, but my previous experience was with Telerik Test Studio and C#.  The transition is going very well for the most part, but I'm trying to find a way to set up data-driven tests in Selenium WebDriver similarly to how they can be set up using Test Studio's Local Data tab (minus the built-in UI, obviously).

I've set up my framework with Apache POI so that I can use Excel files for my data with each row representing a scenario made of different variables represented by the columns.  The problem is that since columns tend to get added or reordered over time, I need a way to refer to any column by the name string in its top row header rather than by its key or index.

Test Studio makes this extremely easy in that once you've copied your spreadsheet to the Local Data tab, you can easily refer to the columns by their header name with something along the lines of...

```
if (...LocalData.PaymentMethod = "CreditCard")...
```

...where `PaymentMethod` is the name of the column and `"CreditCard"` is a potential value in a cell of that column.

Does anyone know of a way to refer to columns by their header name strings using Java in Selenium WebDriver?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I should also note that I don't necessarily need as clean of a way to reference the column as Test Studio provided. While that would be great, my inability to reference the column by its header string contents is the crux of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are messing up Selenium with data reading from excel sheet. Selenium can't do it - Apache POI does. So, I'll answer regarding POI usage.

You can retrieve column headers using `CellReference` utility class and column index:

```
String columnName = CellReference.convertNumToColString(columnIdex);
```

When you've found necessary column, you can read its cells:

```
for(Row r : sheet) {
   Cell c = r.getCell(columnIdex);
   // do what you need

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I noted I am already using Apache POI.  Your suggestion uses the column's index which I am specifically trying to avoid because the index will change as columns are added or reordered requiring manual updates of other many columns' indexes.  I have a lot of columns.